# What is the idiomatic way to break out of a recursion in C?

Tags: c, recursion, break

Suppose we have a recursive function, `f`, that might fail if the input is incorrect.  The error in the input can only be detected while `f` is running.

What is the idiomatic way in C to break out of `f()`, straight to the original calling function, in case of an error?

Is `setjmp`/`longjmp` the usual solution here?

---

Toy example:

```
void g() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, -3, 4};
    int result = f(0, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1, arr);

    /* if f() was successful: */
    printf("%d\n", ); 
    /* if error occurred in f: do something else */
}

int f(int n, int i, int *arr) {
    if (i < 0)
        return n;
    /*
    if (arr[i] < 0) <-- "erroneous input"
        break to g()
    */
    return f(arr[i] + n, i-1, arr);
}
```

Comment: `if(arr[i]<0) return g();` doesn't work? or maybe return some special value (like -1) and deal with it in the calling function?

Comment: `f()` has been invoked from `g()`, so the OP is wanting to drop all the way back to the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options are:

1. Return a status flag from `f()` indicating success or failure. This causes the error to bubble up one level at a time from the depth at which the error occurs, so may not be what you want. Note that this is the only safe option if you need to unwind any allocations or release resources which `f()` may have claimed at each level.
2. Use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` exactly as you suggest to simulate the effect of throwing an exception and jump directly to the error-handling code.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is it return a value indicating an error, mostly `-1` is used.

Comment: Don't know who marked you down, but if you change the code slightly your answer works, i.e. if (arr[i] > 0) return -1. In g() you can check result for -1 and you know your function has failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think `longjmp` is the way to go. I would not at all consider it good coding style, though.
It becomes harder to see what your code does if you start introducing jumps in it. There are also numerous problems:

- code readability suffers
- you can only call your function from one place, thus reuse of the code is severely limited
- [it's easy to introduce memory leaks](http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2009/07/dangers-of-setjmplongjmp.html) when using `longjmp`
- the resulting code is much more brittle (breaks easier, for example when introducing some piece of code above the `setjmp`)

Unless you have very specific performance requirements, try to avoid it and instead let an error result bubble back down to your original caller.

Comment: Why do you think that it is not good style?  Can you give some examples where it might go wrong?  What do I need to watch out for?

Comment: Thank you.  I assume that by "you can only call your function from one place" you mean that `f` (in my example) could only be called from `g`.  This is not a problem because `g` is the interface to `f` that should actually be used.  `f` is just the "internal" implementation of the method.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You could also use some kind of wrapper function that includes nothing else but the function call and the setjmp. I'm not saying you shouldn't do it, my point is just that you should have a reason to do so and that this can easily be abused :)

Answer (score 1):

If the recursion will be deep, I would think `longjmp` makes more sense. Otherwise returning costs an extra `O(N)` (where `N` is the number of levels of recursion), and that includes thrashing the cpu cache with tons of pages of stack frames (each stack frame is likely to be a whole cache line).

Some will argue that `longjmp` is "bad style", and I will agree, but using deep recursion is much worse style already anyway... (And likely to have much worse effects, like blowing away your stack and crashing the program or yielding privilege compromise, not just looking ugly.)

Comment: I take care that recursions be not too deep (e.g. when depth is ~ logarithm of input size then it's okay), and it is not a practical issue for my current application, but I do wonder how to avoid crashes when running out of stack space.  Is there some sort of practical defence against this, such as checking the available stack space beforehand and limiting the recursion depth based on that?  I guess this should be a separate question.

Comment: The only solution is to avoid recursion where the depth is not bounded logarithmically or so. You can replace call recursion with your own recursion-like data structures allocated via `malloc`, but then you'll still have the issue of what to do when you run out of memory, so in my opinion it's really best to avoid algorithms that require huge amounts of working space to begin with, at least when there's a reasonable alternative.

Comment: The difference is that `malloc` won't crash---it'll simply tell me that there's not enough space left. Is there no similarly safe solution when running out of stack space?  I am asking because to be honest I don't have a clue how much stack space is typically available on different systems (as this problem doesn't usually come up).  I could of course measure (see after how many recursive steps it crashes), but that would only be my machine.  To clarify: I'm not having this practical problem (running out of stack space), I just got curious about it.

Comment: I guess my answer wasn't explicit enough. To make it simple, there's no portable way to know how much stack space you have available/remaining. Most modern systems make the default fairly large, but it's sometimes much smaller (by default) in threads other than the main thread. On the other hand, POSIX threads allows you to specifically request a particular stack size for threads you create, but even then you don't know how much the compiler will waste in call frame overhead, etc...

Comment: ...As such, it's really best to always minimize the amount of stack space you use, and let the fact that modern systems generally give you a lot of stack space serve as a "safety net" so you can be sure that your programs never crash from overflowing the stack.